# Redirect an "index.php?module" URL to a new URL with RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect an old URL with the following path:

```
index.php?module=TrackBack&id=58,2814
```

To another one with a permalink like this:

```
new-link/
```

Redirect and RedirectMatch are not valid. I know that I have to use the RewriteRule, but don't know how. I've tried with this:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?module=TrackBack\&id=58,2814$ /new-link/
```

But it doesn't work. What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match query string you will need a `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`.

Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^module=TrackBack\&id=58,2814$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /new-link/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help anubhava, but with your RewriteCond this is the url that I get:
mysite.com/var/www/new-url/?module=TrackBack&id=58,2814

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: Done! BTW, I can't upvote your answer because the system doesn't allow me until my reputation is 15 or higher :-P

Comment: btw I have upvoted your question for explaining the problem really well as a new user on SO.